# Global provider configurable once

Tags: angular, angular5

I am trying to make a config service that can be given an environment value which it then uses to spit back appropriate config values.

Something like this

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class ConfigService {
private env: string;    

SetEnv(value: string) {
    this.env = value;
}

Get() {
    let rtrn;

    if (this.env == "DEV") {
        rtrn = {
            api: "http://localhost:60517/api/"
        }
    }
    else if (this.env == "TEST") {
        rtrn = {
            api: "http://test:60517/api/"
        }
    }
    else { }

    return (rtrn);
}
}
```

Followed by this in `app.module.ts`

```
providers: [
    ConfigService.SetEnv("DEV"),
    ....
]
```

And then used on the following manner after being injected into a component
`ConfigService.Get().api`

The above example throws an error: `app.module.ts:64 Uncaught TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_12__services_config_config_service__.a.SetEnv is not a function`

Something along those lines...but I welcome other suggestions to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't know how to do this when I built my app, but if I were starting today, here is how I would solve your problem:

Have a configuration file that exports the configuration you select, along with a common interface. Let's call it **config.ts**:

```
import { InjectionToken } from '@angular/core';
export interface IConfig {
  api:string,
  env?:string
};
const DEV_CONFIG:IConfig = {
  api:'http://dev.endpoint.com',
  env:'DEV'
};
const TEST_CONFIG:IConfig = {
  api:'http://test.endpoint.com',
  env:'TEST'
};
export const CONFIG_TOKEN = new InjectionToken<IConfig>('config.token');
export const CONFIG_PROVIDER = {
  provide:CONFIG_TOKEN,
  useValue:TEST_CONFIG // <- choose the configuration here
}
```

Add the exported provider to your module's `providers` array:

```
providers: [CONFIG_PROVIDER]
```

Finally, in your component, you inject the configuration this way:

```
export class AppComponent {
  config:IConfig;

  // Inject is imported from @angular/core  
  constructor(@Inject(CONFIG_TOKEN)config:IConfig){ 
    this.config = config;
    }
}
```

Now you have access to the configuration in your component.

- [See the docs](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection#non-class-dependencies)
- [**Live demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cg8rur?file=app%2Fconfig.ts)

Answer (score 0):

You can not call methods from providers into the app.module: This is wrong.

```
providers: [
ConfigService.SetEnv("DEV"),
....
 ]
```

If you want to set env,then set it from your component where you are injecting this service. And look at the above answer, it must give you the solution which you are looking for.

Let me know, if this solves your problem.